# How grab key from api call in this js example

Tags: javascript

So in the API response example below, focusing on env_variables, I am trying grab the value for secret.  I am stuck because as you can see, the name and value are not nested together.  I am not familiar with how to grab the value based on the name in this example.

api response:

```
{
    "id": 1146,
    "job": {
        "name": "jobname1",
    },
    "env_variables": [
        {
            "name": {
                "name": "test1"
            },
            "value": {
                "value": "10.13.6"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": {
                "name": "test1"
            },
            "value": {
                "value": "10.13.6"
            }
        },
    ],
},
{
    "id": 1147,
    "job": {
        "name": "jobname2",
    },
    "env_variables": [
        {
            "name": {
                "name": "secret"
            },
            "value": {
                "value": "10.13.7"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": {
                "name": "test5"
            },
            "value": {
                "value": "10.13.6"
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

js

```
  jobs: []
  apiEndpoint = "test.com/api"
  fetch(this.apiEndpoint)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(body => {
    for(let i=0; i<body.length; i++){
      this.jobs.push({
        'build_id': JSON.stringify(body[i].id),
        'secret':  //not sure how to pull the value (10.13.7)
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: Does every job have `secret`? From your example data only `1147` does?

Comment: not every job has a secret

Comment: The extra level of nesting seems unnecessary. But you can just test `if (response[i].env_variables[j].name.name == "secret")` and then use `response[i].env_variables[j].value.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested loops, since there are two nested arrays: the top level of the response is an array of objects, and `env_variables` contains an array of objects.

```
fetch(this.apiEndpoint)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(body => {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
      let env = body[i].env_variables;
      for (let j = 0; j < env.length; j++) {
        if (env[j].name.name == "secret") {
          this.jobs.push({
            'build_id': JSON.stringify(body[i].id),
            'secret': env[j].value.value
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this inside `.then(body=>...`

```js
const body = [{ //it looks like brackets [] were lost in OP
    "id": 1146,
    "job": {
      "name": "jobname1",
    },
    "env_variables": [{
        "name": {
          "name": "test1"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "10.13.6"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": {
          "name": "test1"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "10.13.6"
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 1147,
    "job": {
      "name": "jobname2",
    },
    "env_variables": [{
        "name": {
          "name": "secret"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "10.13.7"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": {
          "name": "test5"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "10.13.6"
        }
      },
    ],
  }
];
let secret = null;
body.forEach(b => {
  let el = b.env_variables.find(e => e.name.name == 'secret');
  if (el) { //found
    secret = el.value.value;
    return false; //exit forEach
  }
});

console.log(secret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this with [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let data = [{ "id": 1146, "job": { "name": "jobname1", }, "env_variables": [{ "name": { "name": "test1" }, "value": { "value": "10.13.6" } }, { "name": { "name": "test1" }, "value": { "value": "10.13.6" } }, ], }, { "id": 1147, "job": { "name": "jobname2", }, "env_variables": [{ "name": { "name": "secret" }, "value": { "value": "10.13.7" } }, { "name": { "name": "test5" }, "value": { "value": "10.13.6" } }, ], } ]
let jobs = []

data.forEach(({id, env_variables}) => jobs.push({
  build_id: id,
  secret: ((env_variables.find(({name}) => 
    name.name === 'secret') || {}).value || {}).value || 'N/A'
  // ... other props
}))

console.log(jobs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result is an array, you could do something like this:

```
let secrets = results.reduce((result, item) => {
    let secret = item["env_variables"].find((v) => {return v.name.name === "secret"})

    if(secret){
        result.push({id:item.id, secret: secret.value.value});
    }

    return result;
}, []);
```

This would return an array of objects like {id: 1, secret: ""} for each object in your result set that has a secret.

If you don't care whether the secret is present or not, you could modify the code slightly like this:

```
let secrets = results.reduce((result, item) => {
    let secret = item["env_variables"].find((v) => {return v.name.name === "secret"})

    result.push({id:item.id, secret: secret ? secret.value.value : ""});    

    return result;
}, []);
```

Which just leaves with you an empty string on the levels where there is no secret.